# Set host to my wifi interface IP address, but can not capture any packages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

My Mac interfaces:

you see the my en0 `inet 192.168.2.228`, and this is my wifi interface.

```
ldl-MBP:~ ldl$ ifconfig 
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a0:99:9b:17:50:07 
    inet6 fe80::18cb:6f7f:fa39:e968%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.2.228 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:99:9b:17:50:07 
...
```

I set the `host 192.168.2.228` filter in my WireShark Capture Filter:

[image]

But why there can not capture any packages? 
[image]

Comment: With WPA, you can only see broadcast packets, and packets directly addressed to your WLAN station. If you want to capture arbitrary packages, turn off encryption (WPA) on the access point. Alternatively, use the monitor mode, but then you'll have to crack the WPA encryption (not trivial).

Comment: If you're running en0 in monitor mode, switch off monitor mode. @dirkt's explanation  is a definite possibility, but only applies to monitor mode. If you don't need to see 802.11 headers or 802.11-specific frame types (i.e. management and control frames), then you don't need monitor mode.